# Escaping WCF Strings (without sending Objects) to Angular Front End

Tags: sql, vb.net, angularjs, wcf

- this is my first posting so apologies if i'm doing this wrong!

I have a little design and implementation drama - I have a putt load of tables that i need to create forms for, and i really dont want to go down the path of creating Stored Procs/ and vb.Net Objects for each and then creating the WCF webservice functions for each...!

So i was hoping to use Angular on my front end and the ngResource module to a generic WCF service which will return the info needed. These are for Admin Tables so Performance isn't the be-all and end-all :-)

Where it gets tricky, is my WCF Services are generic so in the URI Template i'm asking for the table to update and then the ID to perform CRUD:

```
    <ServiceContract()>
Public Interface IDataStore

    <OperationContract()> _
    <WebInvoke(BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, Method:="POST", RequestFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate:="/{TABLE}/{*ID}")> _
    Function [Save](TABLE As String, ID As String) As String ' RR.Services.DataStore.Response

    <OperationContract()> _
    <WebInvoke(BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, Method:="GET", RequestFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate:="/{TABLE}/{*ID}")> _
    Function [Get](TABLE As String, ID As String) As String ' RR.Services.DataStore.Response

    <OperationContract()> _
    <WebInvoke(BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, Method:="DELETE", RequestFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate:="/{TABLE}/{ID}")> _
    Function [Delete](TABLE As String, ID As String) As Boolean ' RR.Services.DataStore.Response

    <OperationContract()> _
    <WebInvoke(BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, Method:="PUT", RequestFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate:="/{TABLE}/{ID}")> _
    Function [Put](TABLE As String, ID As String) As String ' RR.Services.DataStore.Response


End Interface
```

So now in my 'business tier' here I can easily perform CRUD but the issue i'm having is returning the JSON objects to Angular as .NET adds escaping to the JSON which i think is breaking Angular. (as im trying to return as string as i haven't formall identified an object!)

I've seen links on the web that look like a 'hack'(?!) to fool WCF to stream the content back (and not too sure where this goes) but wondering if there is another way to return a JSON object (i thought through a generically defined object or hashtable or something?) Without me having to specify the returned object in my service definition (as that means i need  service for each table... urgh..!)

```
 Public Class DataStore
    Implements IDataStore

    Function [Save](TABLE As String, ID As String) As String Implements IDataStore.Save  ' RR.Services.DataStore.Response
        Return "Save"
    End Function
    Function [Get](TABLE As String, ID As String) As String Implements IDataStore.Get ' RR.Services.DataStore.Response
        Select Case True
            Case ID = ""
                Return GetJson(RR.DataAccess.Query.ExecuteStringReader("SELECT TOP 100 * FROM " + TABLE, New Hashtable).Tables(0)).Replace("\""", """")
            Case Else
                Return GetJson(RR.DataAccess.Query.ExecuteStringReader("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE + " WHERE  ID = " + ID + "", New Hashtable).Tables(0)).Replace("\""", """")
        End Select
    End Function
    Function [Delete](TABLE As String, ID As String) As Boolean Implements IDataStore.Delete  ' RR.Services.DataStore.Response
        Return "Delete"
    End Function
    Function [Put](TABLE As String, ID As String) As String Implements IDataStore.Put  ' RR.Services.DataStore.Response
        Return "PUT"
    End Function
    Public Function GetJson(ByVal dt As DataTable) As String

        Dim serializer As System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer = New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer()
        Dim rows As New List(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object))
        Dim row As Dictionary(Of String, Object)

        For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
            row = New Dictionary(Of String, Object)
            For Each col As DataColumn In dt.Columns
                row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr(col))
            Next
            rows.Add(row)
        Next
        Return serializer.Serialize(rows)
    End Function
End Class
```

Current output from the WCF String:

```
"[{\"ID\":\"23a812ab-9953-4e4b-bbab-08887dc8bdd8\",\"Company\":\"X\"}]
```

Desired Output:

```
"[{"ID":"23a812ab-9953-4e4b-bbab-08887dc8bdd8","Company":"X"}]
```

Has anyone else come across this and is so what did you do!?! thank you all - any help is much appreciated!! :-)

Comment: This sounds like over-engineering. If all you want is CRUD forms, then a Dynamic Web Site will generate it all for you, and allow you to override any forms that are particularly important.

Comment: Thanks Simon, yeah perhaps but this is part of a bigger system so need to keep the forms in this dashboard (i would love to outsource the forms but they are specific to the app) - i've tried returning hashtables, dictionary(of string, string) arraylists, you name it - but none of them return a nice 'generic JSON object" :-/ any help appreciated!

Comment: Actually, those two strings are identical. The \ characters don't actually exist: they're just VS putting the escapes in before the embedded " characters as you would do if hard-coding the string.